# "Dog is haram" - is it mentioned in Quran or Hadith?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, dogs

We consider dogs to be haram in our culture. Some Muslim regions don't consider dogs as absolute haram too i heard.

I wanted to ask if there is any authentic Hadith or Quranic verse which calls dog as "haram" (like it says for pig).

Please quote for both keeping them and eating them.

Please don't answer if you're going to give logics and scholars statements. I would like to know Quran & Hadith only please.

Comment: @Medi1Saif do you think malikis say it's halal to eat dog ? O.o

Answer (score 2):

Only hadith and Quran, that's what I like.

About eating dogs:

> عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، قَالَ نَهَى رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   عَنْ كُلِّ ذِي نَابٍ مِنَ السِّبَاعِ وَعَنْ كُلِّ ذِي مِخْلَبٍ مِنَ
>   الطَّيْرِ ‏.‏
>
> Ibn 'Abbas reported that Allah's Messenger peace be upon him
>   prohibited the eating of all fanged beasts of prey, and all the birds
>   having talons.
>
> [sahih muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/34/23)

This is a general rule!

About keep them:

> عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ مَنْ أَمْسَكَ كَلْبًا فَإِنَّهُ يَنْقُصُ كُلَّ
>   يَوْمٍ مِنْ عَمَلِهِ قِيرَاطٌ، إِلاَّ كَلْبَ حَرْثٍ أَوْ مَاشِيَةٍ
>   ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَ ابْنُ سِيرِينَ وَأَبُو صَالِحٍ عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ عَنِ
>   النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ إِلاَّ كَلْبَ غَنَمٍ أَوْ حَرْثٍ
>   أَوْ صَيْدٍ ‏"‏‏.‏ وَقَالَ أَبُو حَازِمٍ عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ عَنِ
>   النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ كَلْبَ صَيْدٍ أَوْ مَاشِيَةٍ ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Whoever keeps a dog, one Qirat of the
>   reward of his good deeds is deducted daily, unless the dog is used for
>   guarding a farm or cattle." Abu Huraira (in another narration) said
>   from the Prophet, "unless it is used for guarding sheep or farms, or
>   for hunting." Narrated Abu Hazim from Abu Huraira: The Prophet (ﷺ)
>   said, "A dog for guarding cattle or for hunting."
>
> [sahih al-bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/41/3)

I think there no other type of dog use mentioned in ahadith but those three. That's why you need some scholars' statement to know if some other uses of dogs could be measured on this three.

Comment: There's also mention of a dog in [Al-Kahf](https://quran.com/18).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones this verse is also about dogs : https://quran.com/5/4
hunting animals in the translation is related in the first place to Dogs . cause مكلبين is close to كلب dog ! but the dog of al-alkahf is so special :) there is a cute information about it some scholars said that this dog was mentioned in quran because of Fellowship the righteous and this is a good sign about the Honor of friendship with good people !  there is some sories from   [isra'ilyat](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Isra%27iliyyat) that this dog was with a grazer and followed them  ... BTW how the verse is relevant ?

Comment: becuase he is asking if DOG is haram for eat and keep in islam , and it's known that the shar'ia of ahl-kahf time is not the same of our days !!