# Can You Have a Dog

Tags: halal-haram, animals, dogs, pets

I was thinking about getting a dog we have an extra room to keep it in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Dog is haram" - is it mentioned in Quran or Hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36665/dog-is-haram-is-it-mentioned-in-quran-or-hadith)

Answer (score 1):

Since there are many Shi'a in this forum, I can't speak for the majority of Islam since we had different terms about things. but I will give you a Sunni answer. you're not allowed to have dogs since it is the best to avoid impurity on your praying site. there's a lot of animals you can pet out there. especially cats since our Prophet love them